# Meaning difference between "to be an expatriate was fashionable" and "it was fashionable to be an expatriate"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, idiom-meaning

In the following sentences, do the two have same meaning or is there a difference? If so, it would helpful to have certain examples through which I can understand those nuances that make these different from each other in terms of meaning?

**S1:** Josephine Baker made Paris her home long before **to be an expatriate was fashionable**, and she remained in France during the Second World War as a performer and an intelligence agent for the Resistance

**S2:** Long before **it was fashionable to be an expatriate**, Josephine Baker made Paris her home, and she remained in France during the Second World War as a performer and an intelligence agent for the Resistance

Comment: No difference at all in meaning; 'to be an expatriate was fashionable' doesn't sound right in the second sentence, but stylistically more refined perhaps in the first.

Comment: If you search for terms such as "dummy subject" and "extraposition", you will find discussion of this issue on this website and elsewhere.